# Rails generate not working in a mountable engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-engines

I am using a blog engine from github- [blogo.](https://github.com/greyblake/blogo)

I am unable to run the scripts rails generate or bundle.

``` rails g model usdf
/home/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in ``require': cannot load such file -- rails/cli (LoadError)
    from /home/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in ``require'
    from /usr/bin/rails:9:in ```'
`

This is the error I am getting.It doesnt have a bin directory inside the app. But even when I add bin directory from another engine , the problem persists.The error I get is.

``` bin/rails g model nnsssnf
/home/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in ``require': cannot load such file -- bundler/setup (LoadError)
    from /home/raj/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.5/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in ``require'
    from bin/rails:9:in ```'`

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lacking the `rails` gem. Try installed it first.

```
gem install rails
```

Comment: Hey.. Thanks man .. that worked.. But I dont understand. I already had  rails gem installed.. I have made several rails apps. But rails was installed again wen i ran this.